# Setting the height: TableViewCells with custom Nib that are different sizes

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a TableViewController that has a custom TableViewCell under the identifier "customCell". Heres an image of the configuration of the cell along with the IBOulets connected to it:

[image]

The cell takes information from my backend and presents it. The description text view (just noticed that I accidentally named it descriptionLabel) doesn't allow scrolling so it expands based off of the content that it's holding. The database is being processed correctly from the database, and it's displaying on the app. **The only problem is that the cell is not its correct height.** On the TableViewControl that's registering this cell through its identifier, I automatically set the height of the cell using UITableViewAutomaticDimension in heightForRow:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

but that's not working either. *The only thing that works is when I set the height of each cell to a standard value such as 200. That doesn't work for me because each cell will be a different height because of the length of the textView.

**How do I set the height of a custom nib (tableViewCell) so that it adjusts based off of the content within it instead of setting the height to a specific value?**

Comment: title and descriptionLabel have constraints?

Answer (score 0):

1-Remove both textViews and replace them with labels

2- Title lbl with theses constraints
     top,leading,trailing , .lines = 0

3- Description lbl with theses constraints
     bottom ,leading,trailing to contentView,top to bottom of title lbl , .lines = 0

Off course you can leave the 2 textviews , but you have to give each one an initial height and do this in

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
  super.layoutSubviews()
   self.titleTvHeight.constant = self.titleTv.contentSize.height
   self.desTVheight.constant = self.desTv.contentSize.height
}
```

//

Don't forget to set this in `viewDidLoad` of the VC

```
 tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 200     
 tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Anyway you can remove `heightForRowAt`